# How to Change SIP default port 5060

Tags: port, voip, sip

Port 5060 is blocked in our network, and I was wondering if it was possible to change it to 5222, which is a port used by Google Talk. If it is possible and I do change it, will I still be able to use VOIP properly? Will there be any connectivity issues?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you plan to "change it" ? SIP != VoIP so you shouldn't have issues...

Comment: You can run SIP on any port you like, but how you change it will depend on the kit you have so what SIP/VoIP apps are you using?

Comment: To add on to Linker's comment, a lot will depend on your setup and your service provider. We really can't tell you what is possible for your current situation without knowing anything about it.